# How to return a cursor from database function to another function in activity

Tags: android, android-cursor, cursor-position, forceclose

I am returning  the Cursor from one function in database to another function in activity. Everything working fine but log cat gives the error (which is not causing any problem) to deactivate or close the cursor in called function. If I close it, I can't access it in calling function.I don't know how deactivate works. Also sometime because of force close my database crashes, is it because my cursor is open or because of some other reason?

Called function is in Database class:

```
public Cursor Settings() {
    mDB = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    Cursor data_db = mDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + setting + " ;",
            null);

    return data_db;

}
```

Calling function:

```
public void insert()
{       
Cursor cr = db.Settings();//db is object of database

            if (cr == null)
                otd.insert_setting(value + "", save_path, option);
            else {
                otd.delete_setting();
                otd.insert_setting(value + "", save_path, option);
            }

}
```

Comment: Logcat traces will make your problem clear, so post the same, also post the function you mentioned in question

Comment: can you share the code of both functions?

Comment: Close cursor from calling function..

Comment: close your cursor after accessing it. close cursor on  onPause() or OnDestroy() method.

Comment: i am storing the retuned cursor to local cursor ,the local cursor i am closing local cursor not the cursor of called function will it cause problem@DeepankerChaudhary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we should open and close database before and after use of database

```
public void insert()
{   
db.open();    
Cursor cr = db.Settings();//db is object of database

        if (cr == null)
            otd.insert_setting(value + "", save_path, option);
        else {
            otd.delete_setting();
            otd.insert_setting(value + "", save_path, option);
        }
db.close

}
```

Comment: You should close the cursor before closing the db too.